# Python: pandas.cut labels are ignored

Tags: python, pandas

I want to cut one column in my pandas.DataFrame using [`pandas.cut()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html), but the labels I put into `labels` argument are not applied. Let me show you an example.

I have got the following data frame:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [-0.009, 0.089, 0.095, 0.096, 0.198]})
>>> print(df)
       x
0 -0.009
1  0.089
2  0.095
3  0.096
4  0.198
```

And I cut `x` column like this:

```
>>> bins = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([(-0.2, -0.1), (-0.1, 0.0), (0.0, 0.1), (0.1, 0.2)])
>>> labels = [100, 200, 300, 400]
>>> df['x_cut'] = pd.cut(df['x'], bins, labels=labels)
>>> print(df)
       x        x_cut
0 -0.009  (-0.1, 0.0]
1  0.089   (0.0, 0.1]
2  0.095   (0.0, 0.1]
3  0.096   (0.0, 0.1]
4  0.198   (0.1, 0.2]
```

However, I expected the data frame looking like this:

```
   id      x  x_cut
0   6  0.089    200
1   6  0.089    300
2   6  0.095    300
3   6  0.096    300
4   6  0.098    400
```

What am I missing? How can I get the data frame with correct labels?

Comment: Reason is it is [bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21233)

Comment: @jezrael, thank you. Is there any simple work around, how to get labels I want?

Comment: workaround: `df['x_cut']  = df['x_cut'].map(dict(zip(bins,labels)))`

Comment: I swap arguments... ooops

Comment: @anky_91, thanks a lot! It is working like a charm :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is [bug issue 21233](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21233).

For me working like @anky_91 commented mapping by dictionary created by `zip`:

```
df['x_cut'] = pd.cut(df['x'], bins).map(dict(zip(bins, labels)))
print(df)
       x x_cut
0 -0.009   200
1  0.089   300
2  0.095   300
3  0.096   300
4  0.198   400
```