# Create new columns with incrementation based on other columns

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

i've a dataframe like that :

My dataframe:
[image]

And I would like to transform it like that... :

[image]

If someone can help, thank's a lot

Comment: What are your thoughts and your approach to this problem so far?

Comment: I've work a lot on this so far. 
My thoughts are : I would like to create a new column which would work with a function saying to put 1 if there is 8 in the column of this hour (for the column "exactly 8 hours"). 
Then, I could just sum these 1 in order to have my number of people which have worked 8 hours. 
But there is a lot of problems. 
1. On my function, when I'm trying to equalize 'hours' with 8, I've a problem when I need to precise "a.all) or a.any()" and that's not working 
2. It's not organized at all in my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- have synthesised your data
- pandas provides `pd.cut()` to categorise continuous data
- build the intervals you want `pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples()`
- there is a bug with *labels* [pd.cut() labels bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60846442/python-pandas-cut-labels-are-ignored).  Workaround used.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Date":np.random.choice(pd.date_range(dt.date(2021,1,1), dt.date(2021,1,3)), 10),
    "Code":np.random.randint(100,105, 10),
    "Name":np.random.choice(["Becky","Dan","Sharon","Scott"],10),
    "Building":np.random.choice(list("ABCD"), 10),
    "Role":np.random.choice(["Engineer","Artist"], 10),
    "Hours":np.random.randint(7,10, 10)
})
bins = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([(0, 7.99), (8,8), (8.01, 100)], closed="both")
labels = ["Min_Hours","Normal_Hours","Extra_Hours"]
dfs = df.groupby(["Date",pd.cut(df.Hours, bins).map(dict(zip(bins, 
                                                       labels)))])["Name"].count().unstack()
```

| Date | Min_Hours | Normal_Hours | Extra_Hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 2021-01-03 00:00:00 | 2 | 1 | 0 |

Comment: Thank you so much !
Can you explain your reasoning a little more after the pd.cut?

Comment: `.map(dict(zip(bins, labels))` is the link I provided - if you take that out you will get technical bin labels as columns